# imagemagick convert png 16 bit to raw

Tags: imagemagick, png

I'm trying to convert a 16 bit greyscale PNG to a raw file. The image size is 640*480.

First, identify:

```
$ identify image.png 
image.png PNG 640x480 640x480+0+0 16-bit PseudoClass 65536c 299KB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I'm expecting the result file to be 640*480*2 bytes in size.

Attempt 1:

```
$ convert image.png -depth 16 image.raw
```

This gives a file size of 330805 bytes. Its first 16 bytes look like:

```
0x00000000: 89504E47 0D0A1A0A 0000000D 49484452     .PNG........IHDR
```

Attempt 2:

```
$ convert image.png -depth 16 image.rgb
```

This gives a file size of 1843200 bytes, which is 640*480*2*3.

I'm running imagemagick version 6.7.7-10 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Any ideas?

Comment: So what's wrong with the second option, that looks correct to me.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I want a single channel, 16-bit. The second attempt outputs 3 channels (RGB) 16 bits.

Comment: Please give us a sample image so it is easier to reproduce.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

It occurred to me since answering you, that there is a simpler method of doing what you want, that takes advantage of ImageMagick's little-used `stream` tool, to stream raw pixel data around.

In effect, you can use this command

```
stream -map r -storage-type short image.png image.raw
```

which will read the Red channel (`-map r`), which is the same as the Green and Blue channels if your image is greyscale, and write it out as unsigned 16-bit shorts (`-storage-type short`) to the output file `image.raw`.

This is cleaner than my original answer - though should give identical results.

**Original Answer**

If you write an RGB raw file, you will get 3 channels - R, G and B. Try writing a PGM (Portable Greymap) like this...

```
convert image.png -depth 16 pgm:-
P5
640 480
65535
<binary data> < binary data>
```

The PGM format is detailed [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format), but suffice to say that there is header with a `P` followed by a digit describing the actual subtype, then a width and height and then a `MAX VALUE` that describes the range of the pixel intensities. In your case, the `MAX VALUE` is 65535 rather than 255 because your data are 16-bit.

You can the strip the header like this:

```
convert image.png -depth 16 pgm:- | tail -c 614400 > file.raw
```

If you are converting lots of files of different sizes and dislike the hard-coded `614400`, and are using `bash`, you can get ImageMagick to tell you the size (height * width * 2 bytes/pixel) and use that like this:

```
bytes=$(identify -format "%[fx:h*w*2]" image.png)
convert image.png -depth 16 pgm:- | tail -c $bytes > file.raw
```

Comment: Hi I am Using Kubuntu 16.4  and a get this error :root@luis:/home/luis/Descargas# rpm -Uvh ImageMagick-7.0.2-9.x86_64.rpm 
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
        ImageMagick-libs = 7.0.2-9  needs  for ImageMagick-7.0.2-9.x86
         (....)
        libpthread.so.0()(64bit) needs for ImageMagick-7.0.2-9.x86_64
        libz.so.1()(64bit) needs for ImageMa

Answer (score 7):

`gray` might be the format you want:

```
convert image.png -depth 16 image.gray
```

This command stores each pixel in 2 bytes and nothing else in the file.

Here I provide a minimal synthetic example: https://superuser.com/questions/294270/how-to-view-raw-binary-data-as-an-image-with-given-width-and-height/978432#978432

[image]

`.raw` is not really a "pixel only" format: it does contain some metadata: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format#File_contents